# Identify which query matched in bool query elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm querying my elasticsearch index with a `bool` query. The query itself has a structure similar to this

```
 {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {"multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["field1", "field2"],
                            "query": self.cleaned_stemmed_phrase,
                            "type": "phrase",
                            "fuzziness":"AUTO"
                                        }},
                        {"multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["field3"],
                            "query": self.cleaned_stemmed_phrase,
                            "fuzziness":"AUTO",
                            "boost": 4
                                        }},
                        {"multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["field4"],
                            "query": self.cleaned_stemmed_phrase,
                            "fuzziness":"AUTO"
                                        }},
                        {"multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["field5", "filed6"],
                            "query": self.spaces_removed,
                            "fuzziness":"AUTO"
                                        }},
                        {"multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["field7", "field8"],
                            "query": self.no_space_stems,
                            "fuzziness":"AUTO"
                                        }}
                        ]
             }
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to identify which of all these queries was the one (ones) that matched results. Is there a built-in method of elasticsearch that allows this or do I have to manually do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) and then in the results you'll get the name of the query that matched.

```
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {"multi_match": {
                        "fields": ["field1", "field2"],
                        "query": self.cleaned_stemmed_phrase,
                        "type": "phrase",
                        "fuzziness":"AUTO",
   add name --->        "_name": "query1"
                                    }},
                    {"multi_match": {
                        "fields": ["field3"],
                        "query": self.cleaned_stemmed_phrase,
                        "fuzziness":"AUTO",
                        "boost": 4,
   add name --->        "_name": "query2"
                                    }},
                    {"multi_match": {
                        "fields": ["field4"],
                        "query": self.cleaned_stemmed_phrase,
                        "fuzziness":"AUTO",
   add name --->        "_name": "query3"
                                    }},
                    {"multi_match": {
                        "fields": ["field5", "filed6"],
                        "query": self.spaces_removed,
                        "fuzziness":"AUTO",
   add name --->        "_name": "query4"
                                    }},
                    {"multi_match": {
                        "fields": ["field7", "field8"],
                        "query": self.no_space_stems,
                        "fuzziness":"AUTO",
   add name --->        "_name": "query5"
                                    }}
                    ]
         }
    }
}
```

Then in the results you'll get a `matched_queries` array with the name of the query/ies that matched the document.

```
"_source": {
    ...
},
"matched_queries": [
    "title_query"
],
```