# Elasticseach "should": how to find number of matches

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I have query with few term's

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": { "colors": 5 }
                },
                {
                    "term": { "productTypes": 10 }
                },
                {
                    "term": { "rooms": 18 }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know, which documents matched all 3 term conditions, which - not.
Probably I can do it using score of document, but can't find - how.

"max_score" just max of found documents score, so if no full matched documents - it will be max of partially matched.

I tried to set score of each term to 1 using "constant_score" and compare score with number of filters:

```
{
    "explain": true,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
              { "constant_score": {
                "filter": {  "match_all": {}},
                "boost": 1
              }},
              { "constant_score": {
                "filter": {  "term": { "collection": 14579 } },
                "boost": 1
              }},
              { "constant_score": {
                "filter": {  "term": { "rooms": 19 } },
                "boost": 1
              }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

... but "queryNorm" reduce this score and I can't find how to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843601/identify-which-query-matched-in-bool-query-elasticsearch/36843742#36843742 (hint: use named queries)

Comment: This is look like that I need except one case. Is it possible to filter query using number of matched queries?

Comment: I'm asking because I have other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457998/elasticsearch-with-filtered-child-documents - if change filter to query + add `match_all` query - I can get that I need except I can't filter documents with parents matched only  `match_all`.