# How to retrieve the "found" field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastisearch and have just implemented a search engine and it works great. I`m using Elastic 2.4 due to JDK restrictions, we use Java 7.
I would like to retrieve the field that was found.
For example, this is my data:

```
{
  "result_type": "PERSON",
  "id": 44963408,
  "identificatie": "07725486",
  "name": "andre",
  "lastName": "silva",
  "@version": "1",
  "@timestamp": "2018-07-31T14:32:58.609Z"
}
```

This is how I am querying:

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
query.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("name", autoCompleteText))
.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("lastName", autoCompleteText));
```

As you can see, my search is a generic search, when you type it searches into "name" and into "lastName".
So, when I get the result, how can I know if the hit was on "name" or in "lastName" ?
I tried to get it from hit.getFields(), but it is always null.

How can I do that ?

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843601/identify-which-query-matched-in-bool-query-elasticsearch/36843742#36843742

Comment: Thanks @Val , it did the trick!