# Elasticsearch query to find number of matched terms in should query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for your help to build a solution to the below:

What is this query:
  Query to check if the keyword exists if any one of the five  fields ( like street,city, lastname,country,continent)
  so that I want to check any one of those fields having united states or united kingdom

What I am looking for a help.

get  score 2:
    if both key words "united states" , "united kingdom" found in anyone of these five ( "street","city","lastname","country","continent" ) fields

get  score 1:
   if any one of these key words "united states" , "united kingdom" found in anyone of these five ( "street","city","lastname","country","continent" ) fields

get  score 0:
     if none of these key words "united states" , "united kingdom" found in anyone of these five ( "street","city","lastname","country","continent" ) fields

so that I can show in the front-end result 0/2 or 1/2 or 2/2

Existings query:

```
GET  main_index/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": { 
      "should": [
        { 
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": ["street","city","lastname","country","continent"],
            "query": "united states", 
            "type": "phrase"
          }
        },
        { 
           "multi_match": { 
             "fields": ["street","city","lastname","country","continent"],
             "query": "united kingdom",   
             "type": "phrase"
           }
        }]
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843601/identify-which-query-matched-in-bool-query-elasticsearch/36843742#36843742 (hint: use named queries in order to know which query matched)

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you very much for the help . I got the list of query names by following that approach. Later in the program I have to handle calculation part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this.

(Note: I simplified the the queries below to query on a single `address` field, but the principle remains the same)

**1. Named queries + application logic**

As [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val) mentioned in the comments, you can use named queries (e.g. naming them `us-query` and `uk-query`) to know which item matched on which query.

You can then have your application code parse the `matched_queries` field of each result to know which query matched and assign the relevant score before returning the results to the frontend:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": { 
      "should": [
        { 
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": ["address"],
            "query": "united states", 
            "type": "phrase",
            "_name": "us-query"
          }
        },
        { 
           "multi_match": { 
             "fields": ["address"],
             "query": "united kingdom",   
             "type": "phrase",
             "_name": "uk-query"
           }
        }]
     }
   }
}
```

**2. Function score**

You can use a [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) of type `script_score`, in conjunction with the `filter` argument, to assign the right score to each query.
I personally am not a fan of this solution, as it uses an overly complex query to achieve a fairly simple result, and introduces some repetition in the query.

```
{
  "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "multi_match": {
                        "fields": ["address"],
                        "query": "united states", 
                        "type": "phrase",
                      }
                    },
                    "script_score" : {
                        "script" : {
                          "source": "1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "multi_match": {
                        "fields": ["address"],
                        "query": "united kingdom", 
                        "type": "phrase",
                      }
                    },
                    "script_score" : {
                        "script" : {
                          "source": "1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "multi_match": {
                                        "fields": ["address"],
                                        "query": "united kingdom", 
                                        "type": "phrase",
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "multi_match": {
                                        "fields": ["address"],
                                        "query": "united states", 
                                        "type": "phrase",
                                    }
                                }
                            ]   
                        }
                    },
                    "script_score" : {
                        "script" : {
                          "source": "2"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yesterday I went through Val link and it worked and gave me a list as you mentioned the same in solution 1. And I also like your second solution, since I will get that as a direct score. But will get the score as summed up , if I am having a "must" at the top and two seperate "should" blocks with the each having two checks on united states, uk queries...  Example : Must { { should { usquery1, ukquery1}, {usquery2, ukquery2}} -  I need 4 score if all of them matched , 3 only three of them matched, 2 if only any two of them matched , 0 if none of them etc., Thanks for help.