# Determining How a Document Was Matched in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to make an or search between two different condition trees-

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "bool": { ... } },
        { "bool": { ... } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And it would be helpful to know of the found documents, which of the two conditions (or both) were matched that resulted in this document match.

Is this possible?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843601/identify-which-query-matched-in-bool-query-elasticsearch/36843742#36843742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Tim and @Val. I was looking for `named_queries`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "bool": { "_name": "x", "must": [ ... ] } },
        { "bool": { "_name": "y", "must": [ ... ] } },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`explain` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-request-explain.html) to show how the score was computed. This shows the score for each hit, so it will give the fields that matched and the score.

```
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "bool": { ... } },
        { "bool": { ... } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's helpful. But actually i think i'm looking for named queries